# linux ip routing: 2 default gateways

Tags: linux, networking, routing, raspbian

I'm using the latest Raspbian and have my device connected to 2 LANs that each have a gateway to the internet. (The device is connected to one LAN by an ethernet cable, and to the other by USB - a USB-tethered mobile phone.)

It appears to just work out of the box, because I can access the intenet, and because the routing table was set up like this automatically after plugging in the cables:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
default         192.168.42.129  0.0.0.0         UG    205    0        0 usb0
```

However, **I wonder if the device would still be able to access the internet if the gateway on one of the LANs randomly breaks?** I have iproute2 package installed but I don't know anything about how it works, and haven't really found a good answer on the internet. Thanks.

Comment: What about to disconnect one of the gataway connection and check?
Cable to the ISP for the router, mobile airplane mode for the mobile... After [edit] the question updating the result and ask why it happens what it happens... `:-)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have 2 metrics. 202 will be the one used to route traffic. 205 will be in case of failure. You have FLAGS UG: Up & Gateway. If the U disappear, that means that your gateway is down. It will be down if the juice between your rasp and the router or anything in the middle will break. If the router is buggy, or his internet line is down then the traffic will route to a dead end.

If you want to avoid this scenario, and since it is not a dynamic routing protocol, you will need to build up an SLA strategy.

For instance: a script with "ping -I usb0" to google, and another with -I eth0 to google as well. If the one with lower metrics is up and fails to contact google, change its metric, or dramatically shut it down.
(metrics: ip route add ${address}/${mask} via ${gateway} metric ${number}).

If you change the metric, you can still try the ping, and restore the connection when ping satisfy.

Use very slow ping, and let it have 3 or 4 fails before the switchover.

This is no silver bullet for your problem, but it is a cool scenario to build up some cool and easy scripts :) :).

Answer (score 2):

Your gateways have a different metric, so even though you have two default routes, you'll only ever use one of them. That's a good thing, because the usual internet protocols (TCP, UDP) are not **multi-homed**: You can't use them to form a single connection using multiple local and/or remote IP address, while routing on different paths.

So you can't really use two internet connections at once, unless you do some sort of load balancing, using static criteria. Which is not trivial to set up.

As for what happens if one gateway "randomly breaks", that depends on how it breaks, and how your RaspPi detects the breakage: If one interface goes to the down state, I think (but didn't test) it would use the other default route. If the gateway itself "breaks" (e.g. looses internet connection), but the connection to the RaspPi is fine, the RaspPi would happily continue to use this gateway, breaking internet connection for the RaspPi as well.